# How to use preg_replace to strip a character but only when it is within a wrapper

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to strip ' and " (single and double quotes) from user provided input, but only if it is within an open and close bracket [ ] ... I don't want to strip anything else from the string.

So this:

[font size="10"]

needs to change to

[font size=10]

but this:

[font size=10]The cow says "moo"[/font]

would not strip anything.

This:

[font size="10"]The cow says "moo"[/font]

would change to this:

[font size=10]The cow says "moo"[/font]

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$result = preg_replace('~(?>\[|\G(?<!^)[^]"\']++)\K|(?<!^)\G["\']~', '', $string);
```

explanation:

```
(?>            # open a group
    \[         # literal [
  |            # OR
    \G(?<!^)   # contiguous to a precedent match but not at the start of the string
    [^]"\']++  # all that is not quotes or a closing square bracket
)\K            # close the group and reset the match from results
|              # OR
(?<!^)\G["\']  # a contiguous quote
```

With this pattern, only quotes are replaced, since all other content inside brackets are removed from the match result.

Comment: great solution, this is why I call regexp "write only" expressions :)

Answer (score 0):

Your case is very easy ;(:

```
<?php
$str1 = '
[font size="10"]

needs to change to

[font size=10]

but this:

[font size=\'10\'] my single quoted size is \'OK?\'

[font size=10]The cow says "moo"[/font]

would not strip anything.

This:

[font size="10"]The cow says "moo"[/font]

would change to this:

[font size=10]The cow says "moo"[/font]
';
//
$str1 = preg_replace('/=[\'"]\s?([^\'"]*)\s?[\'"]/', '=$1', $str1);

echo "<pre>";
echo $str1;
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Regex used:

```
=[\'"]\s?([^\'"]*)\s?[\'"]
```

A string startig with an equal sign = followed by a double/single quote preceded by spaces or not...

Answer (score 0):

quick variant which came to my mind (note php 5.3 syntax):

```
$s = preg_replace_callback('/(\\[[^\\]]+])/', function ($match) {
        return str_replace(['"', '\''], ['', ''], $match[1]);
    }, $s);
```